# Linker cannot find symbols in static C library when cross compiling rust to android

Tags: android, c, rust, linker, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile Rust code for x86_64 Android using [Cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross) (I am running macOS 13 with M1 chip).
This code uses symbols from a static C library ([this one](https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng)) that I've built myself.
Upon reaching the link step, I am hit with the error :

```
          ld: error: undefined symbol: espeak_Initialize
          >>> referenced by lib.rs:108 (packages/espeak/src/lib.rs:108)
          >>>               /target/x86_64-linux-android/debug/deps/oratio_espeak-6fba08adc959e6d8.3x6nmh9h9fre8r93.rcgu.o:(oratio_espeak::initialize::h403ba8dd7c5de0ec)
          clang140: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am 100% sure that the library is actually found, because -L/-l flags are properly set, and if I try to change them I get the error "cannot find library".

In order to cross-build the C library I use the following (using Android NDK on M1 mac) :

```bash
PATH=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin:$PATH
CC="x86_64-linux-android33-clang"
CXX="x86_64-linux-android33-clang++"

./autogen.sh
./configure --host=aarch64-apple-darwin --target=x86_64-linux-android
make
```

Here is some info about the resulting archive :

```
$ nm libespeak-ng.a | grep espeak_Initialize
0000000000000000 T espeak_Initialize

$ objdump -f libespeak-ng.a
libespeak-ng.a(libespeak_ng_la-case.o): file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: x86_64
start address: 0x0000000000000000

[repeat for all object files...]
```

What can cause missing symbols even when the library is found and actually contains the symbols?

PS: Here is the exact built library I am trying to link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y9YgkDMrfkpct4ee-ETvRmxXv1zBsSzz/view?usp=sharing

EDIT : Here are the command used for building/linking.

```
$ cross test --target x86_64-linux-android --config target.x86_64-linux-android.linker="'/android-ndk/bin/x86_64-linux-android33-clang'" --config target.x86_64-linux-android.ar="'/android-ndk/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ar'"
```

Note that I also tried without the `--config`, when doing so it changes the linker from `x86_64-linux-android33-clang` to `cc` but gives the same result.

Linker invocation (each argument have been put on newline for readability) :

```
LC_ALL="C"
PATH="/Users/arthur/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/android-ndk/bin:/Users/arthur/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin"
VSLANG="1033"
"/android-ndk/bin/x86_64-linux-android33-clang"
"-m64"
"/tmp/rustcEr0LI7/symbols.o"
"/target/x86_64-linux-android/debug/deps/oratio_espeak-74e896619faec8e7.119cce293ejvq2cd.rcgu.o"
[other similar .rcgu.o ommitted for brevity]
"/target/x86_64-linux-android/debug/deps/oratio_espeak-74e896619faec8e7.2s376qmbbifeevz2.rcgu.o"
"-Wl,--as-needed"
"-L"
"/target/x86_64-linux-android/debug/deps"
"-L"
"/target/debug/deps"
"-L"
"/target/x86_64-linux-android/debug/build/oratio-espeak-7547cefa827890c5/out/espeak-ng/x86_64-linux-android" <-- note: this folder contains libespeak-ng.a
"-L"
"/Users/arthur/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-linux-android/lib"
"-lespeak-ng"
"-Wl,-Bstatic"
"/target/x86_64-linux-android/debug/deps/libespeakng_sys-70bc6650c0b39573.rlib"
"/Users/arthur/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-linux-android/lib/libtest-e3fab4d163e91148.rlib"
[other similar .rlib ommitted for brevity]
"/Users/arthur/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-linux-android/lib/librustc_std_workspace_std-74e842bbf3699e1d.rlib"
"/target/x86_64-linux-android/debug/deps/libparking_lot-27cc7ea2042fb770.rlib"
[other similar .rlib ommitted for brevity]
"/target/x86_64-linux-android/debug/deps/libeither-c29c058d37529903.rlib"
"/Users/arthur/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-linux-android/lib/libstd-37d05f9f3fc29d7b.rlib"
[other similar .rlib ommitted for brevity]
"/Users/arthur/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-linux-android/lib/libcompiler_builtins-3a801941068d9a2c.rlib"
"-Wl,-Bdynamic"
"-lespeak-ng"
"-ldl"
"-llog"
"-lunwind"
"-ldl"
"-lm"
"-lc"
"-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr"
"-Wl,-z,noexecstack"
"-L"
"/Users/arthur/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-linux-android/lib"
"-o"
"/target/x86_64-linux-android/debug/deps/oratio_espeak-74e896619faec8e7"
"-Wl,--gc-sections"
"-pie"
"-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now"
"-nodefaultlibs"
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the link command. Show both the original command and show the invocation of the `ld` command, which you can get with the `-v` switch as the message tells you.

Comment: I edited the question to add original cross command & linker invocation command.

Comment: I cannot correlate the linker error message with the linker invocation. The error message mentions a file `packages/espeak/src/lib.rs`. I do not see where that is listed in the linker invocation. Do you?

Comment: `packages/espeak` is a rust crate named `oratio_espeak`, lines 7-9 in linker command references many `/.../oratio_espeak-74e896619faec8e7.<hash>.rcgu.o`, which I believe contains the code from crate `packages/espeak`.

Comment: Some tests you can perform to help isolate the problem are: Replace `-lespeak-ng` with the absolute path to libespeak-ng.a`. Create an object file that references `espeak_Initialize` and test that linking with `libespeak-ng.a` satisfies the reference. Create an object file that defines `espeak_Initialize` and test that appending it to the link command satisfies the reference.

Comment: Wild guess here, but `-lespeak-ng` appears twice in your command. Maybe the second one gets ignored because there was already the first one, but the `espeak_Initialize` is not found in the first one because the file that refers to it appears after (and order matters with linker command lines).

Comment: I created a test C file referencing `espeak_Initialize`, compiled it with my `libespeak-ng.a` and got `undefined reference to 'espeak_Initialize'` . The library seem faulty.